# use apache.wicket.ServletFileUpload upload files

Tags: file-upload, wicket

I want use apache.wicket.ServletFileUpload upload files But I ran into some problems and I could not get the file
this is my java code and html
[image]

[image]

```
List<FileItem> parseRequest = upload.parseRequest(request);`
```

this i can not get fileItem. I don't know why.Can someone help me thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
ServletWebRequest webRequest = (ServletWebRequest) RequestCycle.get().getRequest();
MultipartServletWebRequest multiPartRequest = webRequest.newMultipartWebRequest(getMaxSize(), "ignored");
multiPartRequest.parseFileParts();
Map<String, List<FileItem>> files = multiPartRequest.getFiles();
```

More info about manually parsing multipart requests could be found at https://wicketinaction.com/2012/11/uploading-files-to-wicket-iresource/

Comment: First thank you very much,The version I use is 1.4.22, and I did not find the methods you mentioned. The reason why I use ServletFileUpload is because the upload component provided by this version cannot select multiple files at once. Now it seems that I have no way to use ServletFileUpload. Am I correct to think so?

Comment: 1.4.22 is too old. I don't remember the details but there is MultiFileUploadField. You can see an example at https://github.com/apache/wicket/blob/wicket-1.4.x/wicket-examples/src/main/java/org/apache/wicket/examples/upload/MultiUploadPage.java

Comment: I have seen this example, but its biggest problem is that you can only select one file at a time, and then select multiple times